# Marking a booking calendar's dates as completely available, partially available, or unavailable

Tags: php, calendar

I'm working on a booking calendar that has check-in and check-out dates. I need to be able to:

1. Display a calendar for any given month
2. For each date on the calendar, indicate whether the date is completely available, partially available, or unavailable

For the first item in the above list, I'm using code from [David Walsh's "Build a Calendar Using PHP, XHTML, and CSS" article](http://davidwalsh.name/php-calendar). In case that link ever goes bad, here is the code:

## The CSS

```
/* calendar */
table.calendar      { border-left:1px solid #999; }
tr.calendar-row {  }
td.calendar-day { min-height:80px; font-size:11px; position:relative; } * html div.calendar-day { height:80px; }
td.calendar-day:hover   { background:#eceff5; }
td.calendar-day-np  { background:#eee; min-height:80px; } * html div.calendar-day-np { height:80px; }
td.calendar-day-head { background:#ccc; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; width:120px; padding:5px; border-bottom:1px solid #999; border-top:1px solid #999; border-right:1px solid #999; }
div.day-number      { background:#999; padding:5px; color:#fff; font-weight:bold; float:right; margin:-5px -5px 0 0; width:20px; text-align:center; }
/* shared */
td.calendar-day, td.calendar-day-np { width:120px; padding:5px; border-bottom:1px solid #999; border-right:1px solid #999; }
```

## The PHP

```
/* draws a calendar */
function draw_calendar($month,$year){

    /* draw table */
    $calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

    /* table headings */
    $headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';

    /* days and weeks vars now ... */
    $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_this_week = 1;
    $day_counter = 0;
    $dates_array = array();

    /* row for week one */
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

    /* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
    for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
        $days_in_this_week++;
    endfor;

    /* keep going with days.... */
    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
            /* add in the day number */
            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';

            /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/
            $calendar.= str_repeat('<p> </p>',2);

        $calendar.= '</td>';
        if($running_day == 6):
            $calendar.= '</tr>';
            if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
            endif;
            $running_day = -1;
            $days_in_this_week = 0;
        endif;
        $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
    endfor;

    /* finish the rest of the days in the week */
    if($days_in_this_week < 8):
        for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
        endfor;
    endif;

    /* final row */
    $calendar.= '</tr>';

    /* end the table */
    $calendar.= '</table>';

    /* all done, return result */
    return $calendar;
}

/* sample usages */
echo '<h2>July 2009</h2>';
echo draw_calendar(7,2009);

echo '<h2>August 2009</h2>';
echo draw_calendar(8,2009);
```

I'm stuck on the second item I have in the list at the top of this question. My goal is to end up with a calendar that looks similar to this:

[image: Calendar example]

I saw the following comment in David Walsh's PHP code:

```
/** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/
```

I *could* put a database query in the place of that comment and have the query look for a row that would cause that date to not be marked as completely available and then, if a row is found, mark it appropriately. The thing I don't like about that idea is that I'd be hitting the database at least 28 times for a single month's calendar. I would rather do one query up front that produces an array like this:

```
$events = array(
    array(
        'check_in_date' => '2014-11-18',
        'check_out_date' => '2014-11-19',
    ),
    array(
        'check_in_date' => '2014-11-19',
        'check_out_date' => '2014-11-21',
    ),
    array(
        'check_in_date' => '2014-11-24',
        'check_out_date' => '2014-11-27',
    ),
);
```

That way, I could do the same logic above, but referring to the array rather than performing a database query. I'm not sure how to go about doing that, though. I saw [this comment on David Walsh's article](http://davidwalsh.name/php-calendar#comment-196878) where somebody achieved this goal, but they didn't post the code that they used. I emailed the person, but it's been close to a week now and I still haven't received a reply.

Any ideas on how best to accomplish the second item I have in the list at the top of this question?

Comment: @AlainTiemblo Consider the `$events` array in my question to be the relevant data from the database. A day is partially booked when it has a check in but no check out or when it has a check out but no check in. Like a hotel. Say there's a room in a hotel that somebody will be staying in for one night (November 18th, for example). After that reservation is made, that room should be considered occupied for the night of the 18th and also for the morning of the 19th but it should be considered vacant for the night of the 19th. Thus, for the 19th, the room is partially booked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
$year = 2014;
$month = 11;

define('FREE', 'free');
define('PARTIAL_CHECKOUT', 'unavailable in the morning');
define('PARTIAL_CHECKIN', 'unavailable from the afternoon');
define('FULL', 'unavailable');

$nb_days = date("t", strtotime("$year-$month-01"));
$begin_month_tm = strtotime("$year-$month-01");
$end_month_tm = strtotime("$year-$month-$nb_days 23:59:59");

$days = array_fill(1, $nb_days, FREE);

foreach ($events as $event)
{
    $check_in_tm = strtotime($event['check_in_date']);
    $check_out_tm = strtotime($event['check_out_date']);

    if (($check_out_tm < $begin_month_tm) || ($check_in_tm > $end_month_tm))
    {
        continue;
    }

    if ($check_in_tm >= $begin_month_tm)
    {
        $inD = (int)substr($event['check_in_date'], strrpos($event['check_in_date'], '-') + 1);
        $days[$inD] = $days[$inD] == FREE ? PARTIAL_CHECKIN : FULL;
    }
    else
    {
        $inD = 0;
    }

    if ($check_out_tm <= $end_month_tm)
    {
        $outD = (int)substr($event['check_out_date'], strrpos($event['check_out_date'], '-') + 1);
        $days[$outD] = $days[$outD] == FREE ? PARTIAL_CHECKOUT : FULL;
    }
    else
    {
        $outD = $nb_days + 1;
    }

    for ($day = $inD + 1; ($day < $outD); $day++)
    {
        $days[$day] = FULL;
    }
}

var_dump($days);
```

With the context:

```
$events = array (
        array (
                'check_in_date' => '2014-10-29',
                'check_out_date' => '2014-11-02',
        ),
        array (
                'check_in_date' => '2014-11-18',
                'check_out_date' => '2014-11-19',
        ),
        array (
                'check_in_date' => '2014-11-19',
                'check_out_date' => '2014-11-21',
        ),
        array (
                'check_in_date' => '2014-11-24',
                'check_out_date' => '2014-11-27',
        ),
        array (
                'check_in_date' => '2014-11-29',
                'check_out_date' => '2014-12-03',
        ),
);
```

You'll get:

```
array(30) {
  [1]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [2]=>
  string(26) "unavailable in the morning"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [6]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [7]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [8]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [9]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [10]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [11]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [12]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [13]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [14]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [15]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [16]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [17]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [18]=>
  string(30) "unavailable from the afternoon"
  [19]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [20]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [21]=>
  string(26) "unavailable in the morning"
  [22]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [23]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [24]=>
  string(30) "unavailable from the afternoon"
  [25]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [26]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [27]=>
  string(26) "unavailable in the morning"
  [28]=>
  string(4) "free"
  [29]=>
  string(30) "unavailable from the afternoon"
  [30]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
}
```

With the context:

```
$events = array (
        array (
                'check_in_date' => '2014-10-29',
                'check_out_date' => '2014-12-03',
        ),
);
```

You'll get:

```
array(30) {
  [1]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [5]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [6]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [7]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [8]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [9]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [10]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [11]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [12]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [13]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [14]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [15]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [16]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [17]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [18]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [19]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [20]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [21]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [22]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [23]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [24]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [25]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [26]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [27]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [28]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [29]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
  [30]=>
  string(11) "unavailable"
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! It's brilliant. Makes perfect sense. It has only one issue. If the check-out date is sometime past the current month, it doesn't behave properly. The way I handled it is I replaced `$days[$outD] = $days[$outD] == FREE ? PARTIAL_CHECKOUT : FULL;` with this: `if (substr($event['check_out_date'], 0, 4) != $year || substr($event['check_out_date'], 5, 2) != $month) {$outD = date("t", strtotime("$year-$month-01")); $days[$outD] = FULL;} else {$days[$outD] = $days[$outD] == FREE ? PARTIAL_CHECKOUT : FULL;}`. Thanks again!

Comment: There were actually some other issues, so I created a separate answer in case anybody else finds this in the future.

Comment: You're right, I did the fixes in my answer too. Thanks & enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Alain Tiemblo's answer got me most of the way there. I couldn't have done it without him. There were some issues with his answer, though, but I get the impression that his answer was meant to be a starting point and not a comprehensive answer anyway, and that's fine. Here is the final code that handles things like check-in dates that are in a month before the month being displayed, check-out dates that are in a month after the month being displayed, etc.:

```
$year = 2014;
$month = 11;
$totalDays = date("t", strtotime("$year-$month-01"));

define('FREE', 'free');
define('PARTIAL_CHECKOUT', 'unavailable in the morning');
define('PARTIAL_CHECKIN', 'unavailable from the afternoon');
define('FULL', 'unavailable');

$days = array_fill(1, $totalDays, FREE);

foreach ($events as $event)
{
    list($inY, $inM, $inD) = explode('-', $event['check_in_date']);
    list($outY, $outM, $outD) = explode('-', $event['check_out_date']);

    if ($inY != $year || $inM != $month)
    {
        // The check-in date is in a month before the month being displayed.

        $inD = 1;

        if ($outD != 1)
        {
            $days[$inD] = FULL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $inD = (int) $inD;
        $days[$inD] = $days[$inD] == FREE ? PARTIAL_CHECKIN : FULL;
    }

    if ($outY != $year || $outM != $month)
    {
        // The check-out date is in a month after the month being displayed.

        $outD = $totalDays;

        if ($inD != $totalDays)
        {
            $days[$outD] = FULL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $outD = (int) $outD;
        $days[$outD] = $days[$outD] == FREE ? PARTIAL_CHECKOUT : FULL;
    }

    for ($day = $inD + 1; ($day < $outD); $day++)
    {
        $days[$day] = FULL;
    }
}

var_dump($days);
```